# Manually setting AES key in openSSL?

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, openssl

I am writing a `SSL Client` using `openSSL` library. I am able to connect to `https://www.httpbin.org` using my C program. However, i want to manually set my own `AES` key for further symmetric cryptography and notify the server about key. I know that key for symmetric encryption is set during handshake process. I am using `SSL_connect()` to connect to server.

How can i manually set key for symmetric cryptography?

Comment: That's probably going to take some hacking. You can change a key with `ChangeCipherSpec` message. However, there are 6 different keys in play, and you might only be changing the 3 on your side of the channel. Changing to a particular AES key probably won't work because derivation occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The key used for encryption depends on data created by both server and client. This means it is not possible to for the client to have full control over the key value. See also [Computing the Master Secret](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-8.1) in RFC 5246 (TLS 1.2).